# Why GCC 8/9/10 and GCC-7 behaves differently in calculating stack shift amount?

Tags: c++, gcc, rust, x86-64, abi

I am porting code to modern compilers and unfortunately encountered a subtle segmentation fault when an FFI function was invoked from Rust to C++.

The stacktrace showed that after the transition to C++, the first argument provided from Rust magically disappeared which misled C++ to use wrong arguments.

The code was somewhat private so I cannot post it here, but the assembly showed something interesting:

In GCC-7 (where the code runs without problem),  the first several lines of assembly look like:

```
   0x0000000000001119 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x000000000000111a <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000000000000111d <+4>:     push   r13
   0x000000000000111f <+6>:     push   r12
   0x0000000000001121 <+8>:     push   rbx
   0x0000000000001122 <+9>:     sub    rsp,0x128
   0x0000000000001129 <+16>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x118],rdi
   0x0000000000001130 <+23>:    mov    rax,rsi
   0x0000000000001133 <+26>:    mov    rsi,rdx
   0x0000000000001136 <+29>:    mov    rdx,rsi
   0x0000000000001139 <+32>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x130],rax
   0x0000000000001140 <+39>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x128],rdx
   0x0000000000001147 <+46>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x120],rcx
   0x000000000000114e <+53>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x140],r8
   0x0000000000001155 <+60>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x138],r9
   0x000000000000115c <+67>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x110]
   0x0000000000001163 <+74>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000000000001166 <+77>:    call   0x116b
   0x000000000000116b <+82>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x128]
   0x0000000000001172 <+89>:    mov    edx,eax
   0x0000000000001174 <+91>:    mov    rcx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x130]
   0x000000000000117b <+98>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x110]
   0x0000000000001182 <+105>:   mov    rsi,rcx
   0x0000000000001185 <+108>:   mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000000000001188 <+111>:   call   0x118d
```

With GCC-8/9/10, however, the assembly becomes

```
   0x0000000000001125 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x0000000000001126 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000000000001129 <+4>:     push   r12
   0x000000000000112b <+6>:     push   rbx
   0x000000000000112c <+7>:     sub    rsp,0x120
   0x0000000000001133 <+14>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x108],rdi
   0x000000000000113a <+21>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x110],rsi
   0x0000000000001141 <+28>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x120],rdx
   0x0000000000001148 <+35>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x118],rcx
   0x000000000000114f <+42>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x128],r8
   0x0000000000001156 <+49>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x130],r9
   0x000000000000115d <+56>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x100]
   0x0000000000001164 <+63>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000000000001167 <+66>:    call   0x116c
   0x000000000000116c <+71>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x118]
   0x0000000000001173 <+78>:    mov    edx,eax
   0x0000000000001175 <+80>:    mov    rcx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x120]
   0x000000000000117c <+87>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x100]
   0x0000000000001183 <+94>:    mov    rsi,rcx
   0x0000000000001186 <+97>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000000000001189 <+100>:   call   0x118e
```

So the logic is almost the same the shift amount is changed? I think the behavior is so strange.

The argument list is something like:

```cpp
struct Opaque {
  char _inner[0];
}
struct View {
  char * base;
  size_t len;
}

ReturnType ffi_function(Opaque*, View, uint64_t, View, uint64_t, uint64_t);
```

I also dumped the stack by `x/-100xg $rbp`

```cpp
0x7fe7a67d41c0: 0x00007fe7a67d41f0      0x0000000014c1b1dc
0x7fe7a67d41d0: 0x000000000000003e      0x0000000000000006
0x7fe7a67d41e0: 0x00007fe7a67d4330      0x00007fe88714b540
0x7fe7a67d41f0: 0x0000000000201000      0x0000000013bd0df1
0x7fe7a67d4200: 0x0000000000000001      0x00007fe7a5e2f4e0
0x7fe7a67d4210: 0x000000000000003e      0x000000000000003b
0x7fe7a67d4220: 0x00007fe7a5e01080      0x00007ffebbd1ddb0
0x7fe7a67d4230: 0x000000001602ff80      0x0000000000000000
0x7fe7a67d4240: 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000000
0x7fe7a67d4250: 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000018d59680
0x7fe7a67d4260: 0x0000000018d59680      0x0000000000000000
0x7fe7a67d4270: 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000000
0x7fe7a67d4280: 0x00007fe700000000      0x0000000000000000
0x7fe7a67d4290: 0x00007fe7a5e2f4e0      0x00007fe88f1630ed
0x7fe7a67d42a0: 0x00007fe7a67d42f8      0x00007fe7a5e2f4e0
0x7fe7a67d42b0: 0x00007fe7a5e2f4e0      0x00007fe88f0d5f42
0x7fe7a67d42c0: 0x00007fe7a5e2f4e0      0x00007fe7a67d43f0
0x7fe7a67d42d0: 0x00007fe7a67d43f0      0x00007fe88f0ffa04
0x7fe7a67d42e0: 0x0000000000000001      0x0000000000000001
0x7fe7a67d42f0: 0x00007fe7a67d43f0      0x00007fe7a5e2f4e0
0x7fe7a67d4300: 0x00007fe7a5e2f4e0      0x0000000000000001
0x7fe7a67d4310: 0x00007fe7a67d43f0      0x00007fe88f0cf1cf
0x7fe7a67d4320: 0x0000000000000006      0x00007fe88714b540
```

Now, it seems that `0x00007ffebbd1ddb0` is the correct value for the first argument but C++ read it as `0x00007fe7a5e01080`

---

update:

Right after the callq, before executing `push %rbp`:

This is what I have got from `x/-100xg $rsp` ($rsp = 0x7fff0b7d4338)

```
0x7fff0b7d4108: 0x00007fff0ae01080      0x000000000000003e
0x7fff0b7d4118: 0x0000003e00000060      0x00007fff0b7d4ab8
0x7fff0b7d4128: 0x00007fff0b7d4310      0x00007fff0b7d4310
0x7fff0b7d4138: 0x00007fff00000004      0x00007fff0b7d41b8
0x7fff0b7d4148: 0x00007fff0ae2f480      0x00007fff00000004
0x7fff0b7d4158: 0x00007fff0b7d41b8      0x00007fff0ae2f480
0x7fff0b7d4168: 0x0000000000000004      0x0000000000000000
0x7fff0b7d4178: 0x00007fff0b7d41b8      0x00007fff0ae2f498
0x7fff0b7d4188: 0x0000000000000000      0x00007fff0ae2f498
0x7fff0b7d4198: 0x00007ffff3d8219e      0x00007fff0b7d41b8
0x7fff0b7d41a8: 0x00007ffff3da157f      0x00007fff0ae01080
0x7fff0b7d41b8: 0x000000000000003e      0x000000000000003e
0x7fff0b7d41c8: 0x0000000000000002      0x000000000000003e
0x7fff0b7d41d8: 0x00007ffff5d4326d      0x00007fff0ae01080
0x7fff0b7d41e8: 0x000000000000003e      0x00007fff0b7d41b0
0x7fff0b7d41f8: 0x00007fff0ae01080      0x000000000000003e
0x7fff0b7d4208: 0x000000000000003e      0x0000000000000004
0x7fff0b7d4218: 0x00007fff0ae2f480      0x00007fff0ae2f498
0x7fff0b7d4228: 0x0000000000000004      0x00007fff0ae2f480
0x7fff0b7d4238: 0x00007fff0ae2f498      0x00007fff0ae2f480
0x7fff0b7d4248: 0x0000000000000004      0x0000000000000001
0x7fff0b7d4258: 0x00007fff0b7fe2a8      0x00007fff0ae2f480
0x7fff0b7d4268: 0x0000000000000004      0x00007fff0ae2f498
0x7fff0b7d4278: 0x00007fff0ae2f498      0x00007fff0ae2f4e0
0x7fff0b7d4288: 0x0000000000000000      0x00007fff0ae2f4e0
0x7fff0b7d4298: 0x00007ffff3e270ed      0x00007fff0b7d42f8
0x7fff0b7d42a8: 0x00007fff0ae2f4e0      0x00007fff0ae2f4e0
0x7fff0b7d42b8: 0x00007ffff3d99f42      0x00007fff0ae2f4e0
0x7fff0b7d42c8: 0x00007fff0b7d43f0      0x00007fff0b7d43f0
0x7fff0b7d42d8: 0x00007ffff3dc3a04      0x0000000000000001
0x7fff0b7d42e8: 0x0000000000000001      0x00007fff0b7d43f0
0x7fff0b7d42f8: 0x00007fff0ae2f4e0      0x00007fff0ae2f4e0
0x7fff0b7d4308: 0x0000000000000001      0x00007fff0b7d43f0
0x7fff0b7d4318: 0x00007ffff3d931cf      0x00007fff0ae2f4e0
0x7fff0b7d4328: 0x0000000000000001      0x00007fff0b7d43f0
```

and `100xg`:

```
0x7fff0b7d4338: 0x00007ffff3dc42fe      0x0000000000000007
0x7fff0b7d4348: 0x0000000000000006      0x00007ffff637393e
0x7fff0b7d4358: 0x00007fff0ae2f480      0x00007fff0b7d4388
0x7fff0b7d4368: 0x00007fff0ae2f480      0x0000000000000060
0x7fff0b7d4378: 0x00007fff0ae01080      0x000000000000003e
0x7fff0b7d4388: 0x0000000000000001      0x00007fff0ae2f4e0
0x7fff0b7d4398: 0x000000000000003e      0x00007fff0ae01080
0x7fff0b7d43a8: 0x0000000013bd0d88      0x00007fffffffbfe0
0x7fff0b7d43b8: 0x00007fff0b7d4420      0x00007fffffffbfa8
0x7fff0b7d43c8: 0x00007fffffffbf50      0x00007fff0b7d4ab8
0x7fff0b7d43d8: 0x000000000000003b      0x0000000000000007
0x7fff0b7d43e8: 0x0000000000000006      0x00007fff0ae2f4e0
0x7fff0b7d43f8: 0x0000000000000004      0x0000000000000001
0x7fff0b7d4408: 0x00007fff0ae2f480      0x0000000000000004
0x7fff0b7d4418: 0x0000000000000001      0x00007fff0ae01080
0x7fff0b7d4428: 0x000000000000003e      0x000000000000003e
0x7fff0b7d4438: 0x00007fffffffbf50      0x00007fff0b7d4ab8
0x7fff0b7d4448: 0x000000000000003b      0x0000000000000007
0x7fff0b7d4458: 0x0000000000000006      0x00007fff0ae2f2a0
0x7fff0b7d4468: 0x000000000000003e      0x00007fff0ae01080
0x7fff0b7d4478: 0x000000000000003e      0x00007fff0ae2f4e0
0x7fff0b7d4488: 0x0000000000000001      0x00007fff0b7d45b0
0x7fff0b7d4498: 0x000001ff0ae2f2a0      0x00007fff0ae2f480
0x7fff0b7d44a8: 0x0000000000000000      0x00007ffff7bb2c60
0x7fff0b7d44b8: 0x00007ffff3daebc6      0x0000000000201000
0x7fff0b7d44c8: 0x0000000000000000      0x00007fffebd4f080
0x7fff0b7d44d8: 0x00007fff0ae2f2a0      0x000000000000003e
0x7fff0b7d44e8: 0x0100000000010301      0x00007fff0ae2f2a0
0x7fff0b7d44f8: 0x000000000000003e      0x000000000000003e
0x7fff0b7d4508: 0x00007fff0ae2f2a0      0x000000000000003e
0x7fff0b7d4518: 0x00007fff0ae2f2a0      0x000000000000003e
0x7fff0b7d4528: 0x00007fff0ae2f2a0      0x0000000060cc0baf
0x7fff0b7d4538: 0x00007fff0ae32180      0x00007fffffffbf50
0x7fff0b7d4548: 0x0000000000000000      0x00007fff0ae32240
0x7fff0b7d4558: 0x00007fff0ae32000      0x0000000000000006
0x7fff0b7d4568: 0x0000000000000007      0x000000000000003b
0x7fff0b7d4578: 0x00007fff0ae3e000      0x00007fff0b7d50b0
0x7fff0b7d4588: 0x00007fff0b7d50b0      0x00007fff0b7d4ab8
0x7fff0b7d4598: 0x00007fff0ae2f480      0x0000000000000004
0x7fff0b7d45a8: 0x0000000000000001      0x00007fff0ae32240
0x7fff0b7d45b8: 0x00007fff0ae32240      0x0000000000000000
0x7fff0b7d45c8: 0x00007fff0ae2f2a0      0x000000000000003e
0x7fff0b7d45d8: 0x0000000000000001      0x00007fff0ae2f480
0x7fff0b7d45e8: 0x0000000000000004      0x0000000000000001
0x7fff0b7d45f8: 0x0000000000000000      0x00007fff0ae3e000
0x7fff0b7d4608: 0x000000000000003b      0x0000000000000007
0x7fff0b7d4618: 0x0000000000000006      0x00007fffebda59d0
0x7fff0b7d4628: 0x00007ffff21bf5cd      0x00007fff0ae32180
0x7fff0b7d4638: 0x00007fff0ae32180      0x00007fff0ae32180
0x7fff0b7d4648: 0x0000000000000000      0x00007fff0b7d4858
```

The frame info of `C++`:

```
 called by frame at 0x7fff0b7d44c0
 source language c++.
 Arglist at 0x7fff0b7d4330, args: server=0x7fff0ae2f498, region_buff=..., peer_id=62, snaps=..., index=62, term=140737324202302
 Locals at 0x7fff0b7d4330, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fff0b7d4340
 Saved registers:
  rip at 0x7fff0b7d4338
```

expected first arg: `0x7fffffffbfe0`

expected second arg: `(0x7fff0ae01080, 0x3e)`

expected third arg: `0x3b`

expected 4th arg: `(0x7fff0ae2f4e0, 1)`

expected 5th, 6th arg: `7`, `6`

Comment: Why do you think your arguments are missing? Arguments are likely passed in via registers (if it was stack, you would see positive offsets with rbp). Compilers will often generate different assembly instructions between versions, it does not mean there's an issue in the compiler. Most likely, the issue is in the c++ code.

Comment: The first argument (`Opaque*`, after transiting from rust to c++) becomes `arg2.base` and so on. It seems that there was a shift in the argument list.

Comment: Actually, I am suspecting there were UBs in C++ code, because with the same rust shared library, gcc-7 compiled code runs smoothly but no the executable from other compilers.

But in the site of the segment fault (where C++ uses `arg2.len` as address which should have been the `base` field), my observation is that there is a wrong shifting of arguments.

Comment: I'd have expected `extern "C"` so the compiler uses the C ABI.

Comment: I suspect that gcc 8/9/10 all have a major bug causing this. It is more likely that your c++ code does not match the requirements to correctly create a c API, and that for gcc 7 you are just lucky that it creates a binary that works.

Comment: I double checked with extern "C" just now. Sadly, no changes to the situation.

Answer (score 6):

Newer GCC does one fewer `push` at the top of the function (saving one fewer call-preserved register).  So it only needs to move RSP by an even multiple of 8 (0x120) to reach a 16-byte alignment boundary before the next call along with reserving enough space, not 0x128.

Both of these things change the distance between RBP and RSP, and thus the `[RBP-0x130]` offsets necessary to reach the space just above RSP to pass large structs by value on the stack.

I didn't check the math, but you can double-check yourself if you still think it's possible that GCC may have a correctness bug.

---

`struct View` only has two pointer-sized members.  As such, the x86-64 System V ABI can pass it in a pair of registers.

And it has no constructors or destructors, or anything else, so the C++ ABI goes along with that.  (I forget the exact rule used to decide whether an object must have an address and thus pass it on the stack.  If your C++ vs. Rust code disagrees about that, it could lead to them disagreeing about how to pass it.)

Update since the problem did turn out to be a non-trivial struct:

- [GCC manual for the `-fabi-version` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fabi-version):

> Version 12, which first appeared in G++ 8, corrects the calling conventions for empty classes on the x86_64 target and for classes with only deleted copy/move constructors. It accidentally changes the calling convention for classes with a deleted copy constructor and a trivial move constructor.
>
> Version 13, which first appeared in G++ 8.2, fixes the accidental change in version 12.

---

As such, the first 6 args (counting the structs as two args) will get passed in RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R10 (in that order), with the rest on the stack.  You can write a simple function to see where it looks for args:

```
int ffi_function(Opaque *server, View region_buf, uint64_t peer_id,
                View snaps, uint64_t index, uint64_t term)
{
    //return region_buf.len;
    return region_buf.len - snaps.len + index;
}
```

[GCC `-Og -fverbose-asm` makes the following asm](https://godbolt.org/z/zaxKeTcor), GCC11 on Godbolt:

```
ffi_function(Opaque*, View, unsigned long, View, unsigned long, unsigned long):
        sub     rdx, r9   # _3, tmp103
        mov     rax, rdx  # _3, _3
        add     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]    # _3, index
        ret
```

(You can see `index` is thus the first stack arg, right above the return address; the earlier ones are in registers.  `snaps.len` is the last register arg, in R9.)

I guessed `uint64_t` as your ReturnType.  If it's a struct larger than 2 registers, then you'll have a pointer to the return-value object as the first arg in RDI, and the other args bumped over by 1.

---

**Your dump matches your expected args just fine.**  I reformatted it so I could add an annotation to each qword (8-byte) stack slot.

```
RSP:
0x7fff0b7d4338: 0x00007ffff3dc42fe (return addr)
                0x0000000000000007 (expected 5th arg = 7)
                0x0000000000000006 (expected 6th arg = 6)
                0x00007ffff637393e (part of the caller's stack frame, not args)
                ...
```

The earlier args are all in registers.

If debug info isn't finding them perfectly, that's perhaps because you compiled with optimization; things get tricky and a callee might not keep a copy of its incoming args anywhere.  Or even if not, getting debug info working right for this can be tricky.

Comment: I updated the dumped stack. Would mind take a look :D

Comment: @SchrodingerZHU: The first argument is a pointer type, so it's in RDI, not on the stack, at the moment of the `call`.  The first *stack* arg will be the first `View`, and will be directly above the return address, 16-byte aligned.  RBP is not part of arg-passing, so you should be dumping relative to RSP right before or after the `call` instruction.  (And if you want anyone to look at anything, make sure you say exactly what point in which version the stack snapshot was taken at.)

Comment: I have updated again. and some additional info: I confirmed that the arguments are messed up before the first `callq` in our own code. Therefore, it should be considered as a stack corruption caused by c++ code.

Comment: @SchrodingerZHU: I saw your update and was already working on one of my own.  Your args are exactly where the calling convention says they should be, with only the last 2 on the stack.  (I didn't notice earlier that your struct was small enough to fit in registers, but it is.)

Answer (score 2):

sorry for my late reply. thanks again for @Peter Cordes.
The problem was finally located and addressed by one of my colleague.

---

it turns out that  `View` was not defined purely trivial. A self defined ctor was added to the struct.

My colleague did twos things to fix the problem:

- remove all ctors to keep the struct trivial
- move all related ffi functions to extern C scope.

I haven't yet taken a look at the generated code but according to the report, the segfault has gone.

---

That is being said, I still think there may be something to think about carefully. If we follow the Itanium ABI strictly, one can see that View is still `trivial for the purpose of call`
and should be passed in the convention of C.

https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#non-trivial-parameters

So even though the original code was somewhat "messy", I think it can be used in FFI? (after all gcc-7 is doing good with that and -Wabi=11/12/13 didn't give any complaints to it).

---

Update:

checked the assembly just now. After the change, `gcc-10` are generating exact the same code as `gcc-7`.

Comment: Oh, so g++-8 changed the C++ ABI rules for your struct?  Yeah that would do it.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html pointed me at  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fabi-version which documents `g++ -fabi-version=0` (the default) vs. *Version 12, which first appeared in G++ 8, [...]. It accidentally changes the calling convention for classes with a deleted copy constructor and a trivial move constructor.*

Comment: quite likely related. however, I do think that the original code should have not been affected. anyway, it is not wise to use dangerous code in every means.